# Inoperative Apiary in Hearthfire

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

The apiary at the Lakeview Manor does not refill with bees or honey. When I first built it, I took all of the bees and honeycombs away on accident. I put two of the bees back thinking they would multiply, but after waiting several months in-game, nothing has happened. Is there a way to make the bees breed and create more honeycombs? I would like to use them for potions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Apiary respawns every 10 in-game days](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Hearthfire/Archive_2#Apiary_and_Chicken_Nests), provided you *are not near the house*.

Simply go away (unload the cell by being in Whiterun or similar -- once you see the loading screen, you're good) and wait about 10 days and come back. The Apiary and everything else that should respawn will respawn.

---

If you are on PC, I ***highly*** recommend that you get the unofficial patches for your game:

- [Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/19/?): Get this no matter what DLC you have.
- [Unofficial Hearthfire Patch](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/25127/?): Will fix a ton of Hearthfire bugs. Get it only if you have the Hearthfire DLC.
- [Unofficial Dawnguard Patch](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/23491/?): Dawnguard bugs? Whassat? Get it only if you have the Dawnguard DLC.
- [Unofficial Dragonborn Patch](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/31083/?): Fixes a lot of Dragonborn stuff. Get it only if you have the Dragonborn DLC.

Comment: Thank you. I kept going near my house. I will be sure to try this soon!

Comment: It is really annoying that we have to go after unofficial patches to fix spawn bugs!